# Замена цифр в строке на символы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

[image]

Какую формулу использовать для замены последних двух цифр на звездочки (**) 
в Google таблицах?
В столбце строк много, вручную просто анриал

Comment: `G1=LEFT(F1,LEN(F1)-2) & "**"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, лучше всего использовать формулу в комбинации с [ARRAYFORMULA](https://contributor.pw/tags/arrayformula/)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(F2:F);"(.*)\d{2}$";"$1**"))
```

Аналогично, но не так красиво, потому что нет приведения типов, пример от @Akina

```
ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(F2:F,LEN(F2:F)-2) & "**")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19nTXHhm8OovxRM0gsmr1WwQA8snRuRn_AnfrEhLnrZQ/edit?usp=sharing)

### Примечание

Может показаться, что формула с `LEN`, какая-то более "простая". Но ее проблема в том, что она так же требует приведения типов или обработки ошибки и ее посимвольная длина в рабочем варианте такая же. Практически любой вариант будет равноценен. А REGEXREPLACE реализует стандарт, без хаков.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(TO_TEXT(F2:F),LEN(TO_TEXT(F2:F))-2) & "**")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=СЦЕПИТЬ(ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;(ДЛСТР(A1))-2);"**")
```

Это для ms excel
где A1 - ячейка нужного вам столбца

Comment: Вопрос вроде про гугл таблицы 

Comment: Ну а в тэгах excel. Может кто-то ищет такое же решение для MS Excel.